# Does Anyone know if there is any incompatibility between COMETD and JERSEY 9? Last version of Jetty is incompatible I think

Tags: maven-2, websocket, embedded-jetty, cometd

After trying to configure maven to work with the last Jetty version (embedded JETTY 9) , I tried to use cometd (last version is 2.5.1) and I figured out that is not possible to make it work.

As you can see below , it seems there is compilation failure is due to type 9.0.0.v20130308 plus version 2.5.1 of artifactID cometd-websocket-jetty.

Honestly I can't get how possible is that the new Jetty version,which improved websocket, doesn't work, I guess I've been doing something wrong so if someone either knows how or have done it please let me know how I can fix it.

By the way I use jdk 1.7.0_09.

```
`[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory
...\apps\business-app\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ SOKO-business ---
[INFO] Compiling 79 source files to 
...\apps\business-app\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] ...\apps\business-app\src\main\java\com\igz\soko\business\Main.java:[38,12]         **error: cannot access ContainerLifeCycle**
[ERROR] ...\apps\business-app\src\main\java\com\igz\soko\business\Main.java:[59,14] **error: method start in class Server cannot be applied to given types;**
[INFO] 2 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.936s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Apr 04 16:12:19 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/177M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-     plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project SOKO-business: Compilation failure:    Compilation failure:
[ERROR] ...\bbv97\apps\business-app\src\main\java\com\igz\soko\business\Main.java:   [38,12] error: cannot access ContainerLifeCycle
[ERROR] ...\bbv97\apps\business-app\src\main\java\com\igz\soko\business\Main.java:  [59,14] error: method start in class Server cannot be applied to given types;`
```

cheers!

D

Answer (score 0):

CometD 2.x is incompatible with Jetty 9.
You can run CometD 2.x on Jetty 7 and Jetty 8, with JDK 5 or greater.

CometD 3 is compatible with Jetty 9, and there will be a CometD 3 preview release soon.